# NGINX + node.js with http-proxy => length added in header

Tags: node.js, nginx

I use node.js behind nginx.The node.js app uses http-proxy.
Basically, the request gets to nginx and is then proxied to the node app:

```
- if static files are requested, the node.js app serves them
- if non static files are requested, the node.js app proxyies the request to a second node.js app (using http-proxy npm).
```

The second case works perfectly when nginx is not in the picture. When nginx is added, the response is quite strange: it's surrounded with strange stuff:

```
"4c\r\n{ json stuff }\r\n0"
```

instead of

```
{ json stuff }
```

To summarize:

1. (without nginx): request for dynamic content -> node.js -> proxy to another node.js app -> response sent back to the user is correct: { json stuff }
2. (with nginx): request for dynamic content -> node.js -> proxy to another node.js app -> response sent back to the user is not correct: "4c\r\n{ json stuff }\r\n0"

I still don't understand what's going on here... any idea ?

**UPDATE**

Hmmm.... seems like it's linked to nginx adding additional header to the request...

My nginx conf is:

```
upstream my_sock {
   server unix:/tmp/test.sock
   fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
   listen 8099;
   client_max_body_size 4G;
   server_name localhost;

   keepalive_timeout 5;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://my_sock;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   }
}
```

Any idea how to remove those additional headers ?

**UPDATE 2**

the 4c added seems to be the length of the response I expect (json stuff). I then added:

```
proxy_set_header Content-Length '';
```

in nginx conf but nothing changed... I still have the 4c displayed... Arg...

Comment: Not specifically related to your question, but if the first node instance is only serving static files, why not just use NginX to do that and then have nginx proxy to the second node instance? NginX is excellent at serving static files.

Comment: You'r right, that is also a good option I'm considering, in fact I already gave it a try and faced the same issue (content-length added). Once I fix this issue I will probably go back to the solution you'r talking about.

Comment: Is that possible to add some logic in nginx conf so that it can proxy a request according to the format of the query string ?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been 6 months, so you probably already know this, but in case someone else finds your question:

This is nginx outputting a chunked transfer encoding (`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`) - as you correctly stated the `4c` is the length of the next chunk (in hex), and the `0` at the end (also hex) states there's nothing more coming (i.e. it's the end of the transfer). This will be misinterpreted by the browser/client if it doesn't also include the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header - I'd check this first.

NodeJS defaults to chunked encoding **unless** you explicitly set the `Content-Length` header. I don't have much experience with nginx but my guess is that if your NodeJS code outputs the `Content-Length` header correctly then nginx should forward this unless you tell it otherwise - so I'd check your NodeJS server's headers. You might also try updating your nginx - I have a vague recollection that earlier versions don't handle chunked transfer encoding very well, though I may be mistaken.

Comment: thanks for your help. I remember doing something totally different from my previous approach as I did not manage to have it working. My bad, I should have updated my post. I'll test your approach. Thanks a lot.